# Enumerating named pipes with search pattern

Tags: c#, .net

In my application (developed with c#) I am using named pipes to open a file in an existing instance. However there can be multiple instances of this application opened. This poses a problem when working with named pipes.

As it stands now, each application opens it's own named pipe "App__x", where x is a number 0 or greater, depending on how many and what instances of an application are opened. When file is to be opened in an existing instance, it is opened in the one with the lowest number.

And now we are starting to come to the problem. To iterate through all the named pipes, I am using a method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789576/is-it-possible-to-discover-named-pipes-in-windows). And the exceptions have been happening - VMware was causing problems.

To battle this I wanted to use a GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern) overload, but it is performing poorly. For example if I call `GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\", "*WI*")`, I get 5 out of 6 Winsock pipes. And if a call `GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\", "*IN*")`, I get 6 out of 6 Winsock pipes.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing such behavior? I have a feeling that such usage of GetFiles was not anticipated and is giving me trouble as a result.